# How does API Gateway validates the JWT token?

Tags: c#, jwt

The documentation states: `API Gateway validates the token on behalf of your API, so you don't have to add any code in your API to process the authentication.`
My question is how?
To authenticate a user, a client application must send a JSON Web Token (JWT) in the authorization header of the HTTP request to the backend API.
So for `API Gateway` to authenticate the user it needs to know the secret key to calculate signature of a header and payload of JWT to compare it with the signature from JWT.
How does it do that?
My code to verify token is like below and I imagine the API gateway would be using something similar to that - so the `_appSettings.Secret` is needed:

```
var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
                var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(_appSettings.Secret);

                tokenHandler.ValidateToken(token, new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
                    ValidateIssuer = false,
                    ValidateAudience = false,
                    // set clockskew to zero so tokens expire exactly at token expiration time (instead of 5 minutes later)
                    ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
                }, out SecurityToken validatedToken);
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're talking about AWS API Gateway; It does require the secret key used for signing the original JWT token but mostly for custom authorization schemes as the documentation states.

> A Lambda authorizer is useful if you want to implement a custom authorization scheme that uses a bearer token authentication strategy such as OAuth or SAML, or that uses request parameters to determine the caller's identity.

To achieve this the API Gateway takes a [Lambda authorizer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-use-lambda-authorizer.html#api-gateway-lambda-authorizer-lambda-function-create) to use in the authorization process. You provide the Lambda authorizer with the required details such as the secret key used to sign your JWT token and it can then verify the token based on that. See this [AWS example](https://github.com/aws-samples/openbanking-brazilian-auth-samples) for more details on the implementation.

The API Gateway will then use the provided detail to verify your JWT tokens and authorize a request.

Comment: I am using for my back end an application based on `aspnet-core-3-signup-verification-api` from Github project. I am not sure what API Gateway is being used – is there a way of checking it? All I know it is c# project based on .NetCore 3.1.
I know the mechanism works, as I have called one control function decorated with the `[Authorize]` meta info. When I tried to use that method without logging in I would get `Unauthorized` error. When I used that method after logging in I did not get any errors.

Comment: Ryhazerus Sorry I got confused.My app is using different mechanism. In Startup.cs it is adding JwtMiddleware.cs to the request pipeline (UseMiddleware<JwtMiddleware>();) which validates JWT token. Thanks for the help.